# Migrate d2d picture migration destination path incorrect

Tags: files, migrations

I'm in the process of building a migration module for a d6 to d7 migration using the [d2d module](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d).

I'm almost there, but one thing that's holding me back is the DrupalPicture6Migration. After trial and error, this is what I have (using the d2d documentation):

```
/* Register the picture migration */

$picture_arguments = $common_arguments + array(
  'machine_name' => 'abcdPicture',
  'description' => t('Import Drupal 6 picture files'),
  'default_uid' => 1,
  'source_dir' => '/',
  'destination_dir' => 'public://pictures',
);
Migration::registerMigration('DrupalPicture6Migration', $picture_arguments['machine_name'], $picture_arguments);
}
```

source_dir points to the correct location: /sites/default/files/userPictures.

I'd expect the migration to go like this:

```
'sites/default/files/userPictures/picture-1589309970.jpg  -> public://pictures/picture-1589309970.jpg.
```

But when I perform the migration, the path gets migrated over instead of the pictures. So I end up recieving this error:

```
'The specified file sites/default/files/userPictures/picture-1589309970.jpg could not be copied to public://pictures/sites/default/files/userPictures/picture-1589309970.jpg.
```

The entire path sites/default/files/userPictures/picture-xx.jpg is copied into the public://pictures directory.

I am reading up on using destination_file but am failing to make the connection on how I'd code this.

Thanks!

Comment: Did u get the answer to this question? because  I am also in the same situation and need answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to specify the destination_dir in the __construct() instead of passing the arguments e.g.

```
class FooUserPictureMigration extends DrupalPicture6Migration {

  public function __construct(array $args) {
    parent::__construct($args);

    // Add simple field mappings
    $this->addFieldMapping('source_dir', FALSE)
         ->defaultValue(MIGRATE_D6_USERPIC_SRC_DIR);
     $this->addFieldMapping('destination_dir', FALSE)
         ->defaultValue(MIGRATE_D6_USERPIC_DST_DIR);
```

Where `MIGRATE_D6_USERPIC_SRC_DIR` is your source dir and `MIGRATE_D6_USERPIC_DST_DIR` is your destination dir (e.g. `public://pictures`).

---

Alternatively you can fix the user avatars by the following one-time query:

```
UPDATE users u
SET picture = (SELECT fid FROM file_managed fm WHERE filename = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(picture, '/', -1) as filename FROM DRUPAL6_DB.users as d6u WHERE name = u.name AND picture <> '' AND fm.filename = SUBSTRING_INDEX(picture, '/', -1)))
  WHERE u.name <> '' 
    AND u.name IN (SELECT name FROM DRUPAL6_DB.users WHERE picture <> '')
```

WHERE `DRUPAL6_DB` is your database name for Drupal 6.